# Different states don't show ui-views

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

### Intro

I'm using AngularJS with the AngularUI module to build an admin interface with several views.

I have a simple Layout for public pages which has one ui-view and another one for admin pages which has four ui-views (header, sidebar, main, footer).

### Problem

The problem I have is if I set the ui-view main the public state won't display the login view, but if I won't set the ui-view main the public state will display the login view. The header, sidebar and footer work with any setting. It seems some setting is overriding another even I tried to set absolute names. Could someone explain what's going on here?

- ui-view="main" ==> Login doesn't show
- ui-view="" ==> Login shows

---

**Visual layout:**

[image: Page layout]

---

**Source code (index.html):**

```
<body>
...
<div ui-view="public">

</div>
<div class="admin">
  <div ui-view="header"></div>
  <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:60px" ui-view="">
                                                     <!-- ^ add main here  -->
  </div>
  <div ui-view="footer"></div>
</div>
...
</body>
```

---

### Code example

I set up a minimal full code example to outline the problem:

[Plunker Edit](http://plnkr.co/edit/TW4mqZfabAOUjDvvqGvW?p=preview)

[Plunker Run](http://run.plnkr.co/jBIFmqnsffKvSGL2/#/admin/home)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've played around with your demo a little bit and had a look at the [ui-router documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

If you change your 'public' state as shown below then it seems to work.

Original:

```
.state('public', {
  url: '/login',
  title: 'Login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
```

Updated:

```
.state('public', {
  url: '/login',
  views: {
    'main@': {
      title: 'Login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html'
    }
  }
})
```

Here is an updated plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/okBWMPpWysS9srKrcxeG?p=preview

Is that what you're trying to do, or are you trying to set up `login` as a nested view?

Comment: This is interesting. I also just got another idea which is different to yours but also makes it work. I created a public state which is abstract and another state for public.login. http://plnkr.co/edit/mYkxgsqVmRAMaZKME4SA?p=preview

Comment: More than one way to skin a cat :) I think the key must be that `views` object because both of the working examples have that.